# HTML5 placeholder plugin for older browsers

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, placeholder

Is there a plugin that will mimic Chrome and Safari's handling of the HTML5 placeholder attribute for older browsers that don't support the attribute.

How Chrome handles the placeholder attribute:

- Placeholder text is added to input box in a lighter color
- Once a character is entered in an input box the placeholder text disappears

For older browsers the plugin should:

- Hide the placeholder text on key press in the input, not on focus
- Use the placeholder attribute to create a label element with the same value that overlays over the input element instead of inserting a value into the input box (don't want the placeholder value to affect submission values or other validation code).

I have already spent some time looking through the available plugins but I have not been able to find something that works as described.

Comment: You can have a look at [Placeholders.js](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) which polyfills the `placeholder` attribute in older browsers. It's not a jQuery plugin, but it does the job well.

Answer (score 0):

There are an *enormous* amount of jQuery plugins that have functionality exactly like this or similar to this. Do a search for "jquery placeholder" and select one that you like.